# Issue with Percolator Analysis Services ( Linq to MDX )

Tags: c#, linq, mdx, cube

I'm trying to create a small sample application which uses Percolator Analysis Services which enables Linq to MDX. I'm talking about this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PercolatorAnalysisServices/

I'm following the guide on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/860143/Introduction-to-Percolator-Analysis-Services-LINQ but I get stuck in the end when typing out a linq statement.

I have the following code:

```
using (var db = new AdventureWorksDW2012Db())
        {
            var mdx = from item in db.AdventureWorksDW2012
                      select new TestClass
                      {
                          TestProp = "test"
                      };

            var data = mdx.ToList();
        }
```

But this results in the following error giving a red squiggly beneath db.AdventureWorksDW2012:

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Cube<AdventureWorksDW2012>'.  'Select' not found.
```

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? I did read that there are newer versions of the API, but I can't seem to find more recent examples/blogs/... which could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I was missing a using statement which enables their API specific LINQ functionality. In case anybody else gets stuck with this, adding the following resolved it:

```
using Percolator.AnalysisServices.Linq;
```

Comment: Glad you solved it. Can you click the checkmark to mark this as the answer?